# Using MySQL C API - check success of inserting rows using prepared statements

Tags: mysql, c, prepared-statement

I'm beginning to learn how to use the MySQL C API and have encountered prepared statements. I haven't used these before in other languages so it's all new to me.

I've looked online and I've figured out how to use prepared statements to retrieve data from a `SELECT` query, and now what I'm trying to do is to `INSERT` some data and find out if it was successful. I've got the first part pretty much down, but **my question is: how can I find out if my `INSERT` was successfully executed?**

I've had a read through some MySQL documents for the C API/prepared statements - and had a Google/search on SO. All I've been able to find examples of are `SELECT` prepared statements and nothing more.

I've attached some code that I've created, which successfully inserts a row.

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "session.h"

char *createSessionId(MYSQL *dbc) {
    const char *sPS2 = "INSERT INTO `sessions` (`SessionID`) VALUES (?)";
    char *sID;
    MYSQL_STMT *stmt;
    MYSQL_BIND param[1];
    unsigned long l = 32;

    // Allocate a statement handle
    stmt = mysql_stmt_init(dbc);
    if(stmt == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to create new session: Could not init statement handle\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Init
    memset(param, 0, sizeof(param));
    sID = malloc(33);
    sprintf(sID, "01234567890123456789012345678901");
    if(mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, sPS2, strlen(sPS2)) != 0) {
        printf("Unable to create new session: Could not prepare statement\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Initialise param structure
    param[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_VARCHAR;
    param[0].buffer = sID;
    param[0].is_unsigned = 0;
    param[0].is_null = 0;
    param[0].length = &l;

    // Bind param structure to statement
    if(mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, param) != 0) {
        printf("Unable to create new session: Could not bind parameters\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Execute prepared statement
    if(mysql_stmt_execute(stmt) != 0) {
        printf("Unable to create new session: Could not execute statement\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    mysql_stmt_free_result(stmt);
    mysql_stmt_close(stmt);

    return sID;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the code in

```
if(mysql_stmt_execute(stmt) != 0) {
        printf("Unable to create new session: Could not execute statement\n");
        return NULL;
}
```

If that fails, you didn't insert any rows. The docs contain a full [example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-stmt-execute.html)

You can also use [mysql_stmt_affected_rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-stmt-affected-rows.html)() after a successful mysql_stmt_execute() to find out how many rows were insterted/updated/deleted.