# How can I write to MYSQL DB as if i were writing to a regular file

Tags: mysql, database-performance, bulk-load

I want to write to MYSQL DB table with the same speed as if i were writing to a regular binary file with ofstream for example.

Normally, Writing 100M bytes to a file using ofstream takes less than 1 second.

While in MYSQL, I inserted these 100M bytes in more than 9 seconds which is very long time ( I used MYISAM table and multiple-row insert statements).

In other words, I want to configure mysql such that it makes no (checks,parsing,....etc), just writing to the table as if it was a binary file

So, Is there any method to achieve that?

**Edit 1:**

Here is the table I want to populate,

```
create table Frames
(
f1 varchar(8) not null , 
f2 varchar(6) not null , 
f3 varchar(6) not null , 
f4 varchar(2) not null ,
f5 varchar(4),
f6 varchar(16000),
f7 varchar(4) not null
);
```

**Edit 2:**

Here is a snippet for the code used for insertion where MAX is defined to 10000

```
for (int c = 0; c < 100; ++c)
{
  string query("insert into Frames (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7) values");
  for (int i = 1; i <= MAX; ++i)
  {
     query += "('AAAAAAAA','000001','000002','05','5005','000000000100000000010000000001000000000100','MKJE')";
     query += (i==MAX) ? ";" : "," ;
  }
  if (mysql_query(conn, query.c_str() )) {
     fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
     return(1);
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: One suggestion if you have any index then drop it before insertion and recreate when your job is completed. Index does affect Insert, Update, Delete operation

Comment: paste the table description

Comment: @jonju : Actually , I dont have any indexes in my table but still very slow in writing ...

Comment: How are you inserting the record? Via front-end app?

Comment: @jonju : yes, via C application. It connects to the DB, construct the insert query in a string, then send it to the server.

Comment: Are you inserting it one by one via a for loop?

Comment: @jonju : Kindly Find the loop used for insertion

Comment: Are you running the database server on the same machine as your application or is there a network connection involved? Also are you using prepared statements or generating a new text string each time? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935835/using-mysql-c-api-check-success-of-inserting-rows-using-prepared-statements

Comment: @Jaydee : the client and the server are running on the same machine.

Comment: have you try to print out the query and run it on workbench or some sort and compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use various tricks for improving the [speed of INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-speed.html). That link is to the MySQL manual, which covers a bunch of tips.

But you'll never get close to the speed of writing directly to a file. MySQL is doing a lot of extra work behind the scenes, to parse SQL, enforce access privileges, enforce data constraints, and convert the data into compact representations of data types, and then organize the data into the file efficiently, and update indexes.

If you use InnoDB (the default) as you storage engine, you always have at least the primary key index to update. InnoDB stores table data as a clustered index.

The only way you can truly get the same speed as if you were appending to a file is by using the [CSV storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/csv-storage-engine.html), and **append directly to that file.**  That is, don't use SQL at all, just write to the data file. If the file is in the right location and has the right name, it will be the data for your MySQL table.

Comment: The CSV Storage engine is a very good idea in my case, But how can i create the .frm and .csm files ..

Comment: Use `CREATE TABLE` as usual, and specify `ENGINE=CSV` at the end. This creates both the .csv data file and the metadata files. Then you can write directly to the data file. Note that there are downsides to the CSV engine too. No indexes, no transactions, no autoincrement PK, no partitioning, no NULLable columns.

Comment: This is a perfect solution , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following steps until you find the performance that are good for you:

1. try [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) statement
2. try Nosql
3. Assuming your mysql instance is properly tuned you have no other choise than  scale vertically your db server and network infrastructure

As final thought, if you don't need mysql features like indexing or ACID why don't you just write to a file. **Because you will never get the same performance as writing to a file**

Comment: Actually, I tried LOAD DATA INFILE but still get bad performance than writing to a regular file