# Mysql trigger that can notify the c code about change in table

Tags: mysql, insert, myisam

I have been searching for a way that can help me notify the C code about successful INSERT operation fired over a  Mysql table.

So the insert query is already there in other component code, now in an independent component I want to get notified when Insert on a particular table takes place so that I could fire select on the table. Currently I fire select query on particular interval, need to avoid that and instead do it after an insert query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using MySQL C API - check success of inserting rows using prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935835/using-mysql-c-api-check-success-of-inserting-rows-using-prepared-statements)

Comment: @P.Salmon No sir, Actually I already have insert query in other component code. Now I just want that to be notified in some other code when insert is fired on a particular table.

Comment: MySQL does not inform a client about modifications. It just responses to requests from clients (e.g. your c app). Instead of relying on an external server to do the talking, you have to modify your components to talk to each other.

Comment: @Solarflare okay. Noted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give users `INSERT` privilege to tables.  Instead, make the go through an API -- either a Stored Procedure or a client API.  There do any monitoring/etc you need.

Note that MySQL cannot (for security reasons) launch anything outside itself -- no email, callbacks, etc.  There is an exception:  UDFs (User Defined Functions).